# How to redirect all requests with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So, here's what my folder structure is like:

```
/
  /public/
     /index.php
     /app/
.htaccess
```

I want that when I type `www.example.com` the request go to the `public\index.php` file but don't display the `public`.
And if I go to `www.example.com\app` it goes to `\public\app` but only shows `www.example.com\app`.

Is that possible with .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site root .htaccess you can use this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash in front of directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# internally forward to /public/...
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: But with this, when I go to `www.example.com/app` it works but show `www.example.com/public/app` in the address bar. How can I hide the `public`?

Comment: Try my updated rules after clearing your browser cache completely.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^$  /public/index.php [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  public/$1 [L]
```